# Add a separate table of content in a HTML bookdown output

Tags: r, bookdown

I created a website using bookdown package and I have a nice table of content on the left, which is fine. 
But now I would like to add the same table of content in a separate chapter (while keeping the toc on the left). I am looking to something somehow similar to what I can do in Latex when using `\tableofcontent` and be able to put the table of content whenever I want in any section. Is there a simple way to do so, without having to manually copy paste content from the html output?

Maybe I am not using the right keywords but I can't find any suggestions on how to do it.